# Error install OpenLdap for RedHat6(checksum error on "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={2}bdb.ldif")

Tags: openldap

I tried to install OpenLdap for linux redhat6, but i recive an error and looks like this

```
"5511c732 ldif_read_file: checksum error on "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}monitor.ldif"
```

below is the code

```
# AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
# CRC32 03c4de5f
dn: olcDatabase={1}monitor
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
olcDatabase: {1}monitor
olcAccess: {0}to *  by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=externa
 l,cn=auth" read  by dn.base="cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com" read  by * none
olcAddContentAcl: FALSE
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcMaxDerefDepth: 15
olcReadOnly: FALSE
olcSyncUseSubentry: FALSE
olcMonitoring: FALSE
structuralObjectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
entryUUID: 7f788d0a-66a8-1034-968a-61cac64128b9
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20150324193414Z
entryCSN: 20150324193414.304614Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20150324193414Z
```

and

```
5511c732 ldif_read_file:  checksum error on "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={2}bdb.ldif"
```

below is the code :

```
# AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
# CRC32 dd2c457a
dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcBdbConfig
olcDatabase: {2}bdb
olcSuffix: dc=example,dc=com
olcAddContentAcl: FALSE
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcMaxDerefDepth: 15
olcReadOnly: FALSE
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com
olcSyncUseSubentry: FALSE
olcMonitoring: TRUE
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcDbCacheSize: 1000
olcDbCheckpoint: 1024 15
olcDbNoSync: FALSE
olcDbDirtyRead: FALSE
olcDbIDLcacheSize: 0
olcDbIndex: objectClass pres,eq
olcDbIndex: cn pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: uid pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: uidNumber pres,eq
olcDbIndex: gidNumber pres,eq
olcDbIndex: ou pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: mail pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: sn pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: givenName pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: memberUid pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: loginShell pres,eq
olcDbIndex: nisMapName pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: nisMapEntry pres,eq,sub
olcDbLinearIndex: FALSE
olcDbMode: 0600
olcDbSearchStack: 16
olcDbShmKey: 0
olcDbCacheFree: 1
olcDbDNcacheSize: 0
structuralObjectClass: olcBdbConfig
entryUUID: 7f7892aa-66a8-1034-968b-61cac64128b9
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20150324193414Z
entryCSN: 20150324193414.304614Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20150324193414Z
olcRootPW: {SSHA}dGaM0fyxrjotXLEKz8Jjl5yoBhpNxLXX
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/example.pem
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/examplekey.pem
```

At first error I had modified  `dn.base="cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com"` =>Manager was with low letter `dn.base="cn=manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com"`
Second error: - `olcSuffix: dc=example,dc=com` => was `olcSuffix: dc=my-domain,dc=com`

```
- olcRootPW: {SSHA}dGaM0fyxrjotXLEKz8Jjl5yoBhpNxLXX  (add)
          - olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/example.pem  (add)
          - olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/examplekey.pem(add)
```

Comment: DNs are case-insensitive so your Manager/manager modification was pointless. I would try removing the CRC32 comment line.

Comment: I've done that, but is not working. :( other solutions?

Comment: Not working how? Same error? Different error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below settings:

```
vim /etc/profile
```

press `SHIFT + g` key combination to go to `EOF` and add `export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"`

```
source /etc/profile
```